# Read public gists from Github and storing values in Reactapp

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, github, github-api

I am creating a webapp on react where when you search for a user you can view that users public gists, files and people who have forked their projects.

I was previously able to get values from https://api.github.com/users?since=1234 by looping through the values:

```
<div>
    {
      users.map((user, i) => {
        return <Usercard
          key={users[i].id}
          //Virtual DOM needs key prop to keep track of cards
          username={users[i].login}
          avatar={users[i].avatar_url}
          profile={users[i].html_url}
          />
      })
    }
</div>
```

However when I use https://api.github.com/gists/public I am a bit lost with the function to read the data from these group of arrays such as files, forks_url, owner properties and so on as I am unable to get the values.

I am calling the data like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(users => this.setState({users: users}));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gist URL https://api.github.com/gists/public

The user info is under owner object, if thats what you are looking for.

Pseudo code for rendering gists info in a table:

```
 const renderUserInfo = data.map((value, key) => {
        return <tr key={key}>
            <td>
                {value.owner.login}
            </td>
            <td>
                {value.owner.url}
            </td>
        </tr>
    });
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you are still having trouble :D

Comment: Ah that makes sense! It worked for those two but in the case of files where I want to get each individual file type I got no luck unfortunately. Example: 

"files": {
      "Upload": {
        "filename": "Upload",
        "type": "text/plain",
        "language": null,
        "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fencer17/d6f2d0b4ab78c216fdecd5c7c2c78189/raw/baa9233acecdb6e325f4891d18cdb77041db7e6a/Upload",
        "size": 2508
      }
    },

where I tried files={users[i].files.filename}

Comment: I guess your initial question was answered. If you think it helped you, you can mark it correct answer :)

Comment: To get file types you can use Object.keys(data.files).map((val) => data.files[val].type ) will output ["application/xml", "text/plain", "text/plain", "text/plain"]..